# Prove that for any positive integer $n$ the number $1 - {n \choose 2}a + {n \choose 4}a^2 - {n \choose 6}a^3+\cdots$ is divisible by $2^{n-1}$.

Tags: contest-math, divisibility

Let $a=4k-1$, where $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Prove that for any positive integer $n$ the number

$$1 - {n \choose 2}a + {n \choose 4}a^2 - {n \choose 6}a^3+\cdots$$

is divisible by $2^{n-1}$.

My attempt: Note that if $k>n$, then ${n \choose k}=0$ (I assume that this is true, but I am not sure about this). Then by the Binomial theorem, the number can be written as

$$(1-a)^n=(2-4k)^n=2^n(1-2k)^n$$

Clearly $2^n(1-2k)^n$ is divisible by $2^{n-1}$.

This question is taken from the book Putnam and Beyond, question $308$, page $104$.

Comment: $(1-a)^n=1-{n\choose 1}a + {n\choose 2}a^2-{n\choose 3}a^3+\cdots$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$A_n =  1-\binom{n}{2}a+\binom{n}{4}a^2-\ldots = \frac{1}{2}\left[(1+i\sqrt{a})^n + (1-i\sqrt{a})^n\right].$$
Provided that:

$$ A_{n+2} = 2 A_{n+1} - (a+1) A_n $$
the claim easily follows by induction.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to obtain $A_n = \frac{1}{2}\left[(1+i\sqrt{a})^n + (1-i\sqrt{a})^n\right]$? I can only obtain $A_n = \frac12 [(1+i\sqrt{a})^{2\lfloor \frac n2\rfloor} + (1-i\sqrt{a})^{2\lfloor \frac n2\rfloor} ]$.